# how do i configure intelij idea for android development in ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Iam new to Intelij IDE some one to help me  configure intelij community edition for android development in ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ 10 Community Edition and further releases natively support Android development (independent of operating system). Check the links below for detailed information.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_android.html

http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_applications_for_Android_in_IntelliJ_IDEA

Comment: thanks for the response but its like the wiki guide is for the ultimate edition and am using the community.